# mysql diff and add diff records into new database

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, data-synchronization

I have two database on two different hosts:

- host A has database A and table A

  - table A contains records with primary key 1 to 10
- host B has database B and table B

  - table B contains records with primary key 1 to 5

Now I have to take a diff of the two separate host/databases/tables
i.e. "host A/database A/table A" contains 1-10 and "host B/database B/table B" contains 1-5 so records 6-10 are missing in host B/database B/table B. Now add these diff records into "host B/database B/table B" from "host A/database A/table A".

In short, update development database with new production data since last update.

What I have tried:

```
mysqldump  --replace --complete-insert --skip-disable-keys --no-create-info -h A
  --port=3306 -u A --password=A database_A table_A 
  | mysql -h B -u B --password=B database_B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump --insert-ignore --extended-insert=FALSE  --complete-insert 
  --skip-disable-keys --no-create-info -h A --port=3306 -u A 
  --password=A database_A table_A | mysql -h B -u B --password=B database_B
```

`--insert-ignore` eventually worked as diff and made the rows unique while dumping data across database.